# Low Seg2Cat Issue

Tags: low, low-seg2cat

hoping someone can help me. Just installed Low Seg2Cat on an EE3 install after finding it to try and rectify duplicate META tags.

I have set it-up as follows but I cant seem to get it working .. it's not being parsed at all.

```
{if segment_1 == "latest-news" AND segment_2 == "category"}
    <title>Latest News | {last_segment_category_name}</title>
{/if}
```

OR

```
{if segment_1 == "latest-news" AND segment_2 == "category"}
    <title>Latest News | {segment_3_category_name}</title>
{/if}
```

Am I missing the complete obvious?

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Is that code in a Snippet/Template Partial or directly in the template?

Comment: Hi Low, it's in a partial.

Comment: Most odd. All of a sudden it started working. Not sure what I changed to make it work again but all seems OK now.

Answer (score 0):

By not being parsed you mean `{last_segment_category_name}` is unparsed and that gets output to your `title` tag html?

Double check your Low Seg2Cat settings
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs#settings

Try setting "Set all segments" to "Yes." Also, make sure you haven't limited the "Category Groups" setting.

Comment: Indeed, yes. Have tried all of that and still it's unparsed :/

Comment: I am also getting not results from this. My code is {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_3_category_id}" dynamic="no" status="open"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries} but it is returning all entries regardless of the category output in seg 3